# Vincular tecla enter con metodo bind

Tags: python, binding

Estoy tratando de vincular la tecla enter a una funcion pero la misma no me devuleve el resultado. La idea es que al ingresar el texto en el widget Entry y al apretar la tecla enter o el boton asociado me devuelva la peticion. Por el momento solo funciona con el Boton pero no con la tecla Enter. Adjunto el codigo.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests


#f1e1c2012a06f3f6d40788d1d0366137
#https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}


def mostrar_respuesta(clima):
    nombre_ciudad = clima["name"]
    desc = clima["weather"][0]["description"]
    temp = clima["main"]["temp"]
    humidity = clima["main"]["humidity"]

    ciudad["text"] = nombre_ciudad
    temperatura["text"] = str (float(temp)) + " °C"
    descripcion["text"] = desc
    humedad["text"] = str (float(humidity)) + " %"


def clima_JSON(ciudad, event):
    API_key = "f1e1c2012a06f3f6d40788d1d0366137"
    URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    parametros = {"APPID" : API_key, "q": ciudad, "units": "metric", "lang":"es"}
    response = requests.get(URL, params = parametros)
    clima = response.json()

    mostrar_respuesta(clima)
        
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("350x550")


def tecla(event):
    clima_JSON


texto_ciudad = Entry(ventana, font = ("Courier", 20, "normal"), justify = "center")
texto_ciudad.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

obtener_clima = Button(ventana, text = "obtener clima", font = ("Courier", 20, "normal"), command = (lambda: clima_JSON(texto_ciudad.get())))
obtener_clima.pack()

ciudad = Label (text = "Ciudad", font = ("Courier", 22, "normal"))
ciudad.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

temperatura = Label (text = "Temperatura", font = ("Courier", 18, "normal"))
temperatura.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

humedad = Label (text = "Humedad", font = ("Courier", 15, "normal"))
humedad.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

descripcion = Label (text = "Descripcion", font = ("Courier", 15, "normal"))
descripcion.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

ventana.bind('<Return>', tecla)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Eso te ayudará a aprender como insertar el código de forma correcta. Cuando utilizas una comilla simple es para marcar pequeñas secciones de código en una `línea` para secciones grandes se utilizan 3 comillas simples al inicio y 3 al final. Saludos!

Comment: Buen día, el vínculo esta hecho correctamente, lo que hace falta es los parámetros de `clima_JSON` adentro de la función `tecla`. Lo probé con `clima_JSON('Tokyo', event)` y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Por cierto, te recomendaría que generes nuevamente tus credenciales ya que las has hecho públicas y alguien podría hacer mal uso de ellas

Comment: Hola HeytalePazguato, Gracias por responder tan rapido.He intentado probar de la manera que me comentas, pero tampoco logro que funcione. En realidad lo que trato de hace es que, al ingresar la ciudad en el Entry y apretar la tecla Enter me devuelva los valores de mostrar_respuesta. En otros programa que no he utilizado una API pude hacer la vinculacion la tecla Enter, pero ente Programa que utilizo la API no me estaria siendo tan sencillo.

Comment: Ok, ya entiendo, pero lo que escribes en el título y cuerpo de tu pregunta no es igual a lo que describes en el comentario, te recomendaría editar la pregunta para que refleje lo que deseas hacer. Voy a revisarlo ahora y formular una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Si, disculpa es que solo tenia en mente solucionar el problema y no como formularlo. Realmente te agradezco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que hace falta es que en la función `def tecla(event)` asignes el argumento de la ciudad que está en el `Entry` `texto_ciudad`

```
def tecla(event):
    clima_JSON(texto_ciudad.get())
```

Otro problema es que la función `clima_JSON` no necesita ningun evento y estas solicitando un argumento `event` que puede ser eliminado

```
def clima_JSON(ciudad):
    API_key = "f1e1c2012a06f3f6d40788d1d0366137"
    URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    parametros = {"APPID" : API_key, "q": ciudad, "units": "metric", "lang":"es"}
    response = requests.get(URL, params = parametros)
    clima = response.json()

    mostrar_respuesta(clima)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
from tkinter import *
import requests


#f1e1c2012a06f3f6d40788d1d0366137
#https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}


def mostrar_respuesta(clima):
    nombre_ciudad = clima["name"]
    desc = clima["weather"][0]["description"]
    temp = clima["main"]["temp"]
    humidity = clima["main"]["humidity"]

    ciudad["text"] = nombre_ciudad
    temperatura["text"] = str (float(temp)) + " °C"
    descripcion["text"] = desc
    humedad["text"] = str (float(humidity)) + " %"


def clima_JSON(ciudad):
    API_key = "f1e1c2012a06f3f6d40788d1d0366137"
    URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    parametros = {"APPID" : API_key, "q": ciudad, "units": "metric", "lang":"es"}
    response = requests.get(URL, params = parametros)
    clima = response.json()

    mostrar_respuesta(clima)
        
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("350x550")


def tecla(event):
    clima_JSON(texto_ciudad.get())


texto_ciudad = Entry(ventana, font = ("Courier", 20, "normal"), justify = "center")
texto_ciudad.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

obtener_clima = Button(ventana, text = "obtener clima", font = ("Courier", 20, "normal"), command = (lambda: clima_JSON(texto_ciudad.get())))
obtener_clima.pack()

ciudad = Label (text = "Ciudad", font = ("Courier", 22, "normal"))
ciudad.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

temperatura = Label (text = "Temperatura", font = ("Courier", 18, "normal"))
temperatura.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

humedad = Label (text = "Humedad", font = ("Courier", 15, "normal"))
humedad.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

descripcion = Label (text = "Descripcion", font = ("Courier", 15, "normal"))
descripcion.pack(padx = 30, pady = 30)

ventana.bind('<Return>', tecla)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Al ingresar la ciudad en el `Entry` y oprimir el botón o presionar la tecla "Enter" ejecuta la función `clima_JSON()` y obtenemos los resultados esperados

[image: Imagen]

Comment: Hola @HeytalePazguato, de verdad te agradezco muchisimo. Quedo funcionando excelente! En una de las pruebas que habia hecho anteriormente intene con el Entry pero no le habia asignado el get. Ahora me pondre a generar de nuevo la key de la API y dejarlo de manera privada. De nuevo muchas Gracias y Saludos!

Comment: No hay de que, si le agregas se fondo una imagen representando el clima se vería genial!